# how to decode list of enum as root element excluding unknown enum

Tags: kotlinx.serialization

this is my json to parse:

```
["AA", "BB", "unknown"]
```

I need to decode with `List<enum>` that doesn't contain `unknown` element. I can get list of 3 element with 1 null or list of 2 element.

i tryed `KindListSerializer` but how to apply to root element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
Json.decodeFromString(KindListSerializer(EnumClass.serializer()), """["AA", "BB", "unknown"]""")
```

Comment: can you please take a look on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73064940/11560810)